# Are there any alternatives for OCI config file?

Tags: typescript, oracle, sdk, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

In the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/Concepts/sdkconfig.htm#SDK_and_CLI_Configuration_File) they said:

> Oracle Cloud Infrastructure SDKs and CLI require basic configuration information, like user credentials and tenancy OCID. You can provide this information by: **Using a configuration file**; **Declaring a configuration at runtime**.

Also, [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/API/Concepts/apisigningkey.htm) they said:

> If you're using one of the Oracle SDKs or tools, supply the required credentials in either a **configuration file** or a **config object** in the code [...].

I would like to know how to provide that information in an object instead of a config file. I haven't found any examples.

I'm receiving account credentials information dynamically as strings, there are no config files.

Here is an example of my code:

```js
import * as identity from "oci-identity"
import common = require("oci-common")

interface Account {
  cliente: string,
  cloud_provider: {
    provider_name: string,
    tenancy: string,
    configFile: string,
    keyFile: string
  },
}

// Credentials
const provider: common.ConfigFileAuthenticationDetailsProvider = new common.ConfigFileAuthenticationDetailsProvider()
const client = new identity.IdentityClient({ authenticationDetailsProvider: this.provider });

const getTenancy = (accounts: Account) => {
  // Create a request and dependent object(s).
  const request: identity.requests.GetTenancyRequest = {
    tenancyId: id
  }

  // Send request to the Client.
  const response = await client.getTenancy(request)
}

const ids = ['id', 'id2', 'id3']

ids.forEach(id => {
  getTenancy(id)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered on https://github.com/oracle/oci-typescript-sdk/issues/175.

In a nutshell, I needed to use `SimpleAuthenticationDetailsProvider` instead of `ConfigFileAuthenticationDetailsProvider`.

This first one allows us to set up credentials like this:

```js
const common = require("oci-common");
const identity = require("oci-identity");

// TODO: Fill in appropriate values for tenancy (str) / fingerprint (str) / passphrase(optional) (str | null) / privateKey (str) / region (common.Region)
const tenancy = "";
const user = "";
const fingerprint = "";
const passphrase = null; // optional parameter
const privateKey = ``;
const region = common.Region.US_PHOENIX_1; // Change to appropriate region

const provider = new common.SimpleAuthenticationDetailsProvider(
  tenancy,
  user,
  fingerprint,
  privateKey,
  passphrase,
  region
);
```